# Use Cases for Attaching Function and Property to Object

Tags: javascript

What sort of use cases would there be for attaching both a function AND property to your object? I haven't seen this done in Production. Is this considered bad practice?

For example:

```
var actor = function() {
    console.log('I\'ll be back!');
}

actor.name = 'Arnold Schwarzenegger';
```

Comment: `function.property=x` just stores a property value on the function's object. It can be useful when you want to "tag" your function with additional variables specific to it. Instead of using general variables like `var name`, using `actor.name` is more readable and scopes the variable under the function. And no, it's not bad practice (in my humble opinion).

Comment: this is actually pretty basic stuff. objects have methods and properties. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Look at the source code of jQuery, it uses this "dual nature" of functions. I.e. `$` actually is defined as a function, not as an object, still having a lot of properties and methods.

Comment: The script doesn't actually work. [Function `.name`s are readonly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), you should get an error trying to set it. Use strict mode!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function inherits from Object. `Function.name` is a special property that refers to the name of the function. For anonymous functions you can change the `name` property to whatever you want.

### Is changing *`.name`* a good practice?

I would say, no. Changing the `.name` property doesn't achieve anything other than making things more confusing.

### Your Question

> *attaching both a function AND property to your object*

This is not what your code is doing. `actor` *is* a function, which is also an object. You can always add properties to any object except `null`. In fact, `Function.prototype` already comes with a lot of methods (properties) as defined in ES6.

### Adding Properties to a Function Instance

In general, adding properties to a function instance is not a bad practice. This practice is used everywhere from creating static methods and even in jQuery (e.g. `$.get`):

```
function Person(name){
    this.name = name;
}

Person.clone = function(p){
    return new Person(p.name);
};

var p1 = new Person("Alex"),
    p2 = Person.clone(p1);       // clone p1
```

It is a feature of the language and you should definitely use it if it fits your purpose.

Comment: When you say that it's not a good practice, you refer specifically to the `.name` property, right?

Comment: Yes. Changing the name property of a Function instance is usually not a good practice IMO.

Comment: I agree, I just wasn't sure whether the OP meant to ask a generic question about properties on function objects and just chose a very bad example

Comment: @Bergi Clarified my answer.